# Access mage.php magento using soap client

Tags: soap-api-v2

I am trying to access some functions in mage.php magento using soap client because i'm working in two different servers how can i do that.

Answer (score 1):

depending on which of the available soap clients you are intending to use. v1 or v2 you can view all of your available commands

{{base_url}}api/v2_soap?wsdl=1

{{base_url}}api/soap?wsdl=1

You will have no access to commands directly in mage.php you must work through wsdl if you plan on using the soap apis.